# Compute sign using secure token hit Unknown error -1073741275 using sha256 algo

Tags: token, digital-signature, sha256, pkcs

I tried to sign the certificate using a secure token, but encountered an unknown error -1073741275. This error occurred when I tried to use the SHA256 algorithm.
Below is my code:

```
cert = certCol(0)
Dim signer As New CmsSigner(cert)

signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly
signer.SignedAttributes.Add(New Pkcs9SigningTime())
signer.DigestAlgorithm = New Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1")
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, False)
encoded = signedCms.Encode()
sSign = Convert.ToBase64String(encoded)
```